# how to use icon on a button (glyphicons) in play framework

Tags: java, html, scala, twitter-bootstrap-3, playframework

I had something like this

```
<button id="search-submit-button" type="submit" name="search-submit-form" class="btn">
    <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
</button>
```

Here I have imported the glyphicons in my project:

[image: here i have imported the glyphicons in my project]

Please, guide me how I can get to use this icon at that button?

Comment: <button id="search-submit-button" type="submit" name="search-submit-form" class="btn"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>

Comment: Hey Check my answer and let me know whether This is what you wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved this few days ago
you have to link them as images 
like this

and try to add some css to it so that it feets as a icon
make sue you get the real icons. .svg, .png or .jpg

Comment: <img id="searchicon"
          src='@routes.Assets.at("images/search.svg")'>

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<button id="search-submit-button" type="submit" name="search-submit-form" class="btn">
    Search <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to replace the ../fonts relative path in the font-awesome.min.css file with /assets/path-to-your-fonts-dir-in-public
i tried this and it worked for me